# linked list implemetation from scratch, segmentation fault

Tags: c, struct, undefined-behavior, singly-linked-list, function-definition

I want to implement linked list from scratch. I programmed it, but when I run it gives me a Segmentation fault in my `node_adder(int data)` function. I don't know what caused this.

```c
struct linked_list
{
    int value;
    struct linked_list *next;
};

struct linked_list *head = NULL;
struct linked_list *tail = NULL;

void node_adder(int data)
{
    struct linked_list *new = NULL;

    new->value = data;
    new->next = NULL;

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = new;
        tail = new;
        printf("head added\n");
    }
    else
    {
        tail->next = new;
        tail = new;
        printf("tail added\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: "*i want to implement linked list from scratch*" - why? In C++, there are standard `std::list` and `std::forward_list` containers for that purpose. Are you coding in C instead? In any case, there are a bazillion questions on StackOverflow regarding the *proper* way to manually implement a linked list.

Comment: `new` is a reserved keyword in C++, don't use it for variable names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `node_adder()`, you are not allocating any memory for the new node before accessing its members.

Try this instead:

```
struct linked_list
{
    int value;
    struct linked_list *next;
};
    
struct linked_list *head = NULL;
struct linked_list *tail = NULL;

void node_adder(int data)
{
    struct linked_list *newNode;

    // ADD THIS!!!
    // in C:
    newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct linked_list));
    // in C++:
    newNode = new linked_list;
    //

    newNode->value = data;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = tail = newNode;
        printf("head added\n");
    }
    else
    {
        tail->next = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
        printf("tail added\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This line initializes a pointer to a node to NULL:

```
struct linked_list *new = NULL;
```

Yet, no memory is allocated for this node. Therefore, in this line, attempting to assign a value to one of the members of the node leads to a segmentation fault:

```
new->value = data;
```

You probably meant to do this:

```
struct linked_list *new = malloc(sizeof(struct linked_list));
```

Of course, a corresponding `free(..)` should also be added when the allocated memory will no longer be used.

Answer (score 0):

For starters it is a bad idea to declare global variables and define functions that depend on the global variables as you are doing

```
struct linked_list *head = NULL;
struct linked_list *tail = NULL;
```

because in this case you will not be able to define for example more than one list.

It is much better to introduce one more structure like for example

```
struct node
{
    int value;
    struct node *next;
};

struct linked_list
{
    struct node *head;
    struct node *tail;
};
```

As for your problem then you are using a null pointer to access memory that results in undefined behavior

```
void node_adder(int data)
{
    struct linked_list *new = NULL;

    new->value = data;
    new->next = NULL;
    //...
```

You need to allocate a node dynamically as for example

```
int node_adder(int data)
{
    struct linked_list *new = malloc( sizeof( *new ) );
    int success = new != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new->value = data;
        new->next = NULL;

        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = new;
        }
        else
        {
            tail->next = new;
        }

        tail = new;
    }

    return success;
}
```

But using the approach I showed in the beginning of my answer You could write instead

```
struct node
{
    int value;
    struct node *next;
};

struct linked_list
{
    struct node *head;
    struct node *tail;
};

int node_adder( struct linked_list *list, int data )
{
    struct node *new = malloc( sizeof( *new ) );
    int success = new != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new->value = data;
        new->next = NULL;

        if (list->head == NULL)
        {
            list->head = new;
        }
        else
        {
            list->tail->next = new;
        }

        list->tail = new;
    }

    return success;
}
```

and in main you can write

```
int main( void )
{
    struct linked_list list = { .head = NULL, .tail = NULL };

    node_adder( &list, 10 );
    //...
}
```